# Price of thing going up

Tags: price

I read about price differences of things throughout years. I read that in 1988 gas costed about .90 cents per gallon; In 2018 it cost about 2.90 per gallon. So in 30 years I think that came to 222.22.%, +7.40% increase in cost per year. I think they say that well maybe pay goes up too, just I found that in 1989 a physicians pay came to about 256k yearly. In 2018 they may have an averages salary of 299k, ~16.79% over 30 yrs, ~+.55% annually. This either seems concerning, or makes no sense that things may go up so much more than pay?

I also read an apple in 1988 cost .06 cents, in 2018, .43 cents, 30 yrs, +20.5% increase in cost yearly.  Does it make sense that cost of these things, often important things go up this much?

Can someone clarify? Thanks

Comment: Just a quick note on notation: ".06 cents" means 6/100 of a cent (it is less than 1 cent).

Comment: Apples rising from 6 cents each to 43 cents each is a **7%** inflation rate, not 20.5% rate.

Comment: Some thing have gone down in price - e.g. computers. Why is it surprising that other things could have gone up in price more than wages?

Comment: And gasoline increasing from 90 cents to $2.90 is a 4% inflation rate, not 7.4%.  So you really need to redo your math.

Comment: Also, according to https://www.statista.com/statistics/236871/retail-price-of-apples-in-the-united-states/ the price of apples increased **2.1%** from 1995 to 2017.  You **really** need fact and math checks.

Comment: Also, the price of apples depends very much on the time of year and the variety of apples.  (And prices are usually per lb/kg, not per apple.)  You may be comparing apples to apples, but there are still differences between McIntosh, Rome, Red Delicious, Gala, Honeycrisp...

Comment: @JadeFlag Sorry, but 222% increase over 30 years is indeed 4% per year.  [0.90 * 1.04^30 = 2.92].  222/30 = 7.4 is the wrong calculation.

Comment: If you're trying to compare wage growth to inflation this is the wrong way to do it. You need to look at broader averages, not just physicians and apples and gasoline. Look at average wage growth and average US Consumer Price Index (CPI). That will give you a better picture as to whether wages for most people are keeping up with the cost of living. Even then, there are exceptions as the overall cost of living (including CPI) can be significantly different in different parts of the country (e.g. San Francisco vs. Omaha)

Comment: Can you explain why you find per year percent increase from total like this mark? Thanks. So if I look at average wage growth, and average CPI it will make more sense? Prices of things like food and gas still seem rising fast from whatever information I read

Comment: #1 There's more than just apples and gasoline and doctors' salaries, so your view is too narrow.  #2 Your math is **very wrong**.

Comment: @Jade when looking at growth you use a _geometric_ average. So over 30 years the average growth of the price of apples would be `(0.43/0.06)^(1/30) - 1 = 6.7%`

Comment: What is your question? Just "does it make sense?"?

Comment: Where I live, gasoline costs $7 USD per gallon. What are you complaining about?

Comment: I think you know what I'm talking about, or maybe (sadly for you), you don't. Well, it seems many people here missed the forest for the trees. Basically does it make sense, does it seem sustainable, proper, does it seem concerning, "This either seems concerning, or makes no sense that things may go up so much more than pay?"; "Can someone clarify? Thanks". I'm not, "complaining", normally I wouldn't even respond to such a funny comment, but why not. I clearly use this for questions, and answers, data, and information. You don't even know what I pay (not that it matters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always helpful to cite the sources you're looking at.  When you're talking about inflation, the government publishes tons of statistics that you can rely on.  There are also plenty of less reliable sites, though, either have bad data, are highlighting exceptional issues (i.e. some random commodity has seen huge price increases), or are comparing many factors other than inflation (i.e. the average salary of all doctors declines if many doctors choose to work fewer hours than they did 20 years ago).

The [US inflation calculator](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/) site gives a good overview of some of the inflation rates.  Between 1988 and 2018, the cumulative rate of inflation was 112.3% (for an annual rate of roughly 2.5%).  The Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) often separately reports the inflation rate for food, energy, and core inflation because food and energy prices tend to be more volatile.  Gasoline averaged [$0.964 in Dec 1998](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/inflation/gasoline-inflation-in-the-united-states/).  It averaged $2.794 in December 2018 for a 3.6% average rate of inflation which was a bit ahead of inflation overall.  [Food inflation between 1988 and 2018](https://www.usinflationcalculator.com/inflation/food-inflation-in-the-united-states/) was just slightly faster than the overall rate of inflation at ~2.6% per year.  Logically, since energy and food are two components of overall inflation and both were slightly higher than overall inflation, core inflation must have been a bit below the 2.5% average to make up for it.

There are lots of ways to look at the rate of wage growth-- generally you're going to look at changes for subsets of the population (i.e. by gender, race, age, etc.) and decide whether you want to look at top earners, median earners, low earners, etc.  Otherwise, it's relatively easy to draw incorrect conclusions if you're comparing raw numbers when the workforce has a lot of relatively young workers at the low end of the salary scale (i.e. when the baby boomers were just getting into the workforce) vs. a later period when a much larger fraction of the population was in their peak earning years.  If you look at [Table 1 of this Congressional Research Service paper on Real Wage Trends 1979 - 2018](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R45090.pdf), you'll see that real wages (that is, wages after accounting for the inflation rate we discussed earlier) increased for almost every category, often by quite a bit.  So most people are seeing their wages increase faster than the rate of inflation.  If you want to explore the data in more detail, the Federal Reserve Bank of Atlanta has [this page](https://www.frbatlanta.org/chcs/wage-growth-tracker.aspx) where you can slice and dice the data to your heart's content.

Comment: Wow. Awesome. Thanks!! So this doesn't concern you at all?

Comment: @JadeFlag - Define "this".  If you look at, say, men at the 10th percentile of earnings, you'll see that their wage rates failed to keep up with inflation.  That's surely a concern even if the overall trend is positive.  You can look at things that aren't part of the consumer price index that have risen in cost faster than inflation-- health care and education being prime examples and see issues.

Comment: Agreed. Brilliant. Thank you. I will do more research. I can try to specify a bit more, theres just a lot of information. But it does seem a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

This is just basic economics.  There are three factors at work: supply & demand, cost of production, and inflation.  So let's apply those to gasoline.

Supply & demand is basic to economics. 30 years ago, there was less demand for oil.  The developed world (places that had lots of cars 30 years ago) had fewer peopple - 245 million in the US, vs around 330 million now. Places like China & India are also joining the car-buying world. This means that there is more demand for the limited supply of oil, so producers sell it to the highest bidder, driving up the cost.

At the same time that demand has increased, many of the easy-to-exploit oil wells have been exhausted.  There is oil that's more difficut to get, from fracking, tar sands, deep sea drilling, &c.  But that oil costs more to produce.  Saudi oil might cost something like $10/barrel to produce (though the Saudis charge more), while oil from fracking might cost $50-$80/barrel, if not more.  Oil producers aren't going to sell their oil below cost (at least not for very long), so if you want oil, you have to pay their price.

Finally, there is inflation.  That's essentially the government printing more money.  (Though these days it's done electronically.)  The classic example is the hyperinflation in post-WWI Germany: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_the_Weimar_Republic

Comment: Should taxation be included as a separate fourth factor in that initial list?  I suspect fuel taxes (and on other products, sales taxes/VAT type taxes) have only increased over the years, and become an increasing proportion of prices of many products.

Comment: @timday: I don't think taxation is a big factor in the change in gas prices in the US.  (Different in other countries, of course.)  Federal taxes haven't been raised since 1993 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_taxes_in_the_United_States ), which means they've actually decreased in inflation-adjusted dollars.  Federal & state taxes together account for only about 1/6 of the current price.

Comment: Thanks I think this added to the inquiry. I do still think something seems off, generally it looks like costs of important things are outgrowing pay and dollar value. There seems a problem.